# Drag, Drop, and Append not positioning div element correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop, append

I have two div elements. I want to drag the first div then want to drop and append it to another div. Drag is working well but when i drop the first div, it goes outside of the targeted div area. I don't want it to go outside of targeted area.
Here is code

```
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function()
    {
        $("#x").draggable();
        $("#y").draggable().droppable(
        {
            drop: function(event,ui)
            {
                $(this).append($(document.getElementById("x")));
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div  id="y" style="width:300px;height:300px;background:#89A94B;" ></div>
        <div  id="x" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:#50555B;" ></div>

    </body>
```

here is  demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nkd6c6m/)
please help.

Answer (score 1):

I've just adjusted your Fiddle a bit: [Drag and Drop](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/fw69g0ef/2/)

```
$("#x").draggable({
 revert: 'invalid' 
});


$("#y").droppable({
 accept: '#x',
 tolerance: 'fit',
 drop: function (event, ui) {
    // do stuff
  } 
});
```

Don't know what you want to happen in case the #x is placed outside of #y - I just used
the option `revert: 'invalid'` for #x so #x stays inside of #y in case of successful drop,
and the option `tolerance: 'fit'` for the dropzone #y, so #x won't stay inside of #y in case it's not completely inside #y.

Update: Added 2nd version. Now the #x is appended as child of #y and is just
placed in the middle of #y using CSS, overriding the settings of the draggable - droppable UI. As it's not totally clear what is required, pls feel free to add another comment, but I think probably this is what you want to happen:

Demo: [Appending draggable as child of droppable](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/6nkd6c6m/41/)

Adjusted your original Code as follows:

```
$(function () {
  $("#x").draggable();
  $("#y").draggable().droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).append($("#x"));
        $("#x").draggable('disable');
    }
  });
});
```

#x is now appended to #y, in addition I disable draggable() for #x when #x is dropped.

CSS:

```
#y {
 overflow:hidden;
}
#y #x {
   background:red !important;
   position:absolute !important;
   top:0 !important;
   left:0 !important;
   margin-left: 25px !important;
   margin-top: 25px !important;
}
```

When #x is appended to #y, I set the background to red and override the UI settings, positioning #x just in the middle of #y. In addition, I set #y overflow: hidden; which is the main problem because of the UI-settings - it'd be possible just to adjust the UI CSS but think this is easier done with some additional CSS like suggested. With overflow: hidden, you won't see anything of #x displayed outside of #y when #x is appended "into" #y - like in the fiddle in your question. It'd be possible to write a function for correct positioning, but as I'm not sure about what the result should look like and you only require the dropped div to stay inside the dropzone, this could match your requirements and you can adjust the CSS to get the result you're looking for.

Comment: thank you, but the #x is not get appended to #y. #x should be a child of #y. please write the append code at  **// do stuff area** and try. it wont work..   [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fw69g0ef/3/)

Comment: @user2013766 Just added a 2nd version in my answer, maybe that's matching the result you're looking for.